# Blender doesn't recognize addon for importing files

Tags: add-on

So I got an addon for importing .anim files into Blender, it says it's enabled as an addon, but when looking for the option to import one, it doesn't show up. How could I get this to work?

Comment: Can you link to the add-on?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/278000231528792065/618597442589425674/Brawl_Scripts_9-3-19.zip

Comment: Some scripts for importing are embedded into the UI, make sure you check out Tools / other HUD elements, it's also possible it's not supported for your Blender version.

Comment: It says to use it for Blender 2.8x, I have 2.80, I'm guessing they're the same

Comment: Arre sure it does not appear in File-Import->Brawl Animation (.anim)? Also check there are no errors in the System console. Window menu toggle System console.

Comment: There's no errors in the console